# InvoiceDate < INvoiceDate.Addmonths(-)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, if-statement

I have a statement...

```
if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12))
```

This checks the date on the Invoice, if it is less than 12 months ago I.E anything before Jan 2012, proceed with the code.

So instead of dateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)) I want to say 6 months from the date on the invoice

I've tried...

```
if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < lastInvoice.Invoice_Date.AddMonths(-0-worksite.Number_of_Months))
```

Also tried without the (-0) and just had it as (0) but need the - for the expression.
Anyway it's not returning what it should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you want it the other way around? You want to continue if today is more than 6 months later than the date on the invoice?

Comment: What is it returning?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastInvoice.Invoice_Date` will never be less than `lastInvoice.Invoice_Date.AddMonths(-anything)`.

This should work for you:

```
if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-worksite.Number_of_Months))
```

If that isn't giving you the correct answer, I'd use the debugger to confirm that worksite.Number_of_Months is actually what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < lastInvoice.Invoice_Date.AddMonths(-0-worksite.Number_of_Months))
```

You're comparing `Invoice_Date` against itself.  You probably want to compare against `DateTime.Now` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `worksite.Number_of_Months` return type is integer, 
 else use `-Convert.ToInt32(worksite.Number_of_Months)` and you should compare it to `DateTime.Now()`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the answer to my comment above, I think you want:

```
if (DateTime.Now > lastInvoice.Invoice_Date.AddMonths(6))
```

Or more accurately:

```
if (DateTime.Now > lastInvoice.Invoice_Date.AddMonths(worksite.Number_of_Months))
```